# print JS object in a div with new line instead of \n

Tags: javascript

I am printing some JS object in a div. JS object is having a key with value being a string with newline.

**String**

```
one
two
three
```

Expected value in div:

```
one
two
three
```

What I am getting in div

```
one\ntwo\nthree
```

**Code:**

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea");
const log = document.querySelector("#log");

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', (event)=>{
 log.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({name:event.target.value});
});
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newline characters are not permitted in JSON; `JSON.stringify` will never result in a string with a literal newline character. Stringifying something with a newline character will result in the output string containing a literal backslash character, followed by a literal `n` character, which is what you're seeing here.

If you actually need `JSON.stringify`, replace all `\n`s in it with actual newline characters.

Another problem is that newline characters do not normally result in actual newlines in the rendered HTML, for most elements. You might use a `<pre>` instead of a `<div>`, since `<pre>`s *do* render newlines in their contents as actual newlines:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea");
const log = document.querySelector("#log");

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  log.textContent = JSON.stringify({
    name: event.target.value
  })
    .replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
});
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
<br>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

(keep in mind that the contents of the `#log` element will *not* be valid JSON - you won't be able to copy its contents and `JSON.parse` it)

Answer (score 0):

Use escape character \

```
{"name":"one\\ntwo\\nthree"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to replace `\n` with `<br>`
2. Should use `keyup` instead of `keypress` otherwise you could only get the current value in the `textarea`

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea");
const log = document.querySelector("#log");

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{
 log.innerHTML = event.target.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
});
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace keypress by keyup

```js
const log = document.querySelector("#log");
const textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea");


textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{
 log.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({name:  event.target.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')})

});
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<br>
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```